# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'latLng')

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Now, I am trying to create an app with react and I am using Google Map API for the project.

I got this error but I have no idea why this occurs.

If anyone knows any clues please let me now.

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import { Paper, Typography, useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core';

import useStyles from './styles'


const Map = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)')

  const coordinates = { lat: 0, lng: 0 }

  return (
    <div className={classes.mapContainer}>
      <GoogleMapReact>
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'AaosjbnsajsnbjIUYIkbbaskjbd' }}
        defaultCenter={coordinates}
        center={coordinates}
        defaultZoom={14}
        margin={[50, 50, 50, 50]}
        options={''}
        onChange={''}
        onChildClick={''}
      </GoogleMapReact>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple `>` is misplaced. Instead of passing props , unintentionally, you are passing children to the component.

```
   <GoogleMapReact>
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'AaosjbnsajsnbjIUYIkbbaskjbd' }}
        defaultCenter={coordinates}
        center={coordinates}
        defaultZoom={14}
        margin={[50, 50, 50, 50]}
        options={''}
        onChange={''}
        onChildClick={''}
      </GoogleMapReact>
```

change it to this:

```
   <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'AaosjbnsajsnbjIUYIkbbaskjbd' }}
        defaultCenter={coordinates}
        center={coordinates}
        defaultZoom={14}
        margin={[50, 50, 50, 50]}
        options={''}
        onChange={''}
        onChildClick={''}>
      </GoogleMapReact>
```

Comment: Oh yes? What have you changed and why? How is it going to solve the issue?

Comment: @MrUpsidown a simple ```>``` was misplaced. Instead of passing props , unintentionally he was passing children to the component.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that should be part of your answer. Never place an answer without any explanation about what you have changed and why (and how it will solve the problem).

Comment: @MrUpsidown Duly noted. Thx for the tip. I edited the answer as per your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at GoogleMapReact props
`<GoogleMapReact ...props></GoogleMapReact>`

Comment: This is the component OP is using. What should OP be looking at? Right now, your answer is "very low quality". Please improve or delete it.